# github action to build ear file

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there any github action that will build ear file ? I am able to build the war file. we have maven based Java webservice application and we will deploy the ear to web sphere application server.

Answer (score 0):

You can take inspiration from [`daggerok/spring-boot-multi-java-ee-apps`](https://github.com/daggerok/spring-boot-multi-java-ee-apps/blob/308bb4d24cf0b77f810e4e5303c694e3c1030fbb/.github/workflows/ci.yml) which uses Docker combined with  [`actions/setup-java@v3`](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) to setup an environment in which you can `mvn` your project.

It ends with `./mvnw -f webapps-deploymen docker:build docker:start`, and uses this [`webapps-deploymen/pom.xml`](https://github.com/daggerok/spring-boot-multi-java-ee-apps/blob/308bb4d24cf0b77f810e4e5303c694e3c1030fbb/webapps-deploymen/pom.xml) (including a `<packaging>ear</packaging>`)